# Fetching a photo in a Tumblr text post using jQuery and JSON

Tags: jquery, json, tumblr

My background in jQuery and JSON is fairly weak, so I'm learning the Tumblr API as I go along. I'd like to fetch the src attribute from first photo in the most recent "regular-post." The image in the post has a class of "main".

Thus far I've been able to fetch the post title into a span and the post URL into a hyperlink that encompasses the image / span.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://features.futurevague.com/api/read/json?callback=?',
        function(response) {
           $('a#feat0').attr('href',response.posts[0].url);
           $('span#feat0').wrapInner(response.posts[0]['regular-title']);
           $('img#feat0').attr('src',response.posts[0]['regular-body'].find('img.main')[0].attr('src'));
    });
});
```

The third function, however, does not work (and is probably malformed).

My HTML I'm embedding the content into looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="feat0">
    <div class="imgholder">
        <img src="#" class="main" id="feat0">
    <span id="feat0"></span></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

So any help using the jQuery `.find()` method?

Comment: are you getting any error on, let's say, Firebug?

Comment: @gpasci I'm not too familiar with firebug, but chrome's inspector gave me the following for the line the img script is on: "Uncaught TypeError: *then the entirety of the tumblr post's body in html format*  has no method 'find'"

Comment: What's the value of response.posts[0]['regular-body'] ??

Comment: @Eric the most recent tumblr post's text-body with html markup (eg `<img class="main" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/310248_214580331941526_101088363290724_552032_691739705_n.jpg"/><p>Kidnap Kid&#8217;s been making waves in the music scene with his past few releases. Just yesterday, (and I&#8217;m excited about this) his track &#8220;Vehl&#8221; got airplay on BBC Radio 1.</p>` )

Comment: Read my answer, i will update there instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have 2 ids with the same value, for starters. Also, post the value of response.posts[0]['regular-body'], it will help..
Remove the id from the span and go

```
$('#feat0').find('img:first').attr('src', response.posts[0]['regular-body']);
```

From the comment in your post :
response.posts[0] is a String here and not HTML ! So you can't use "find" on it. You should go regex or even indexOf to extract the image source.

Comment: an example of how to use indexOf to get an element's attribute.

Comment: Now that's just plane lazy. I'm about to down vote the whole thread. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `regular-body` is just a string, thus the dom selector doesn't work..
Try with

```
$(response.posts[0]['regular-body']).find('img.main')[0].attr('src')
```